# VBA Excel - Copying and Pasting Column Width/Groupings

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy the entire worksheet from "DNU" into each proceeding worksheet. I'm looking to do a regular paste to keep the width and groupings but this will only paste the formulas and table format. Thank you.

Here is the code:

~

```
Dim wsVar As Worksheet
Dim i as Integer
With ThisWorkbook
    For i = 6 to .Worksheets.Count
        .Worksheets("DNU").Range("A1:Y200").Copy destination:=.Worksheets(i).Range("A1:Y200")
    Next 
End With
```

Comment: Depending on the sheet, it may be easier to copy the sheet and clear what you don't need. This will preserve all formats

Answer (score 1):

You dont't need to use `copy/paste`. `Value` can have `arguments`, `11` transfers both value and formats.

```
Dim i As Integer
With ThisWorkbook
    For i = 2 To .Worksheets.Count
        .Worksheets(i).Range("A1:Y200").Value(11) = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Y200").Value(11)
        'Unsure how you accomplish your grouping,
        .Worksheets(i).Range("A1:Y200").OutlineLevel = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Y200").OutlineLevel

        Dim colx As Long
        For colx = 1 To 25
            Worksheets(i).Columns(colx).ColumnWidth = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(colx).ColumnWidth
            Worksheets(i).Columns(colx).OutlineLevel = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(colx).OutlineLevel
        Next

        Dim rowx As Long
        For rowx = 1 To 200
            Worksheets(i).Rows(rowx).OutlineLevel = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(rowx).OutlineLevel
        Next

    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! The formatting keeps the same but for some reason the groupings disappear. Is there a way to include the groupings from the "DNU" worksheet? Or does this have to get automated for each worksheet?

Comment: @Hiimtroymcclure; I updated the answer to copy your groupings. I don't use groups so it may not work. please use it on a copy. If it does not work you may have to reapply your groups using vba.

Comment: Thanks GMalc, I'm running into a Run-Time Error: Unable to get the OutlineLevel property of the Range Class. Like you mentioned, I'll probably have to reapply the groupings.